# How to properly use unions with route params for react-navigation-v6 in Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

When using `react-navigation-v6` with Typescript, I've been encountering `ts-lint` errors such as this one: `Property 'variable' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ variable1: string; } | { variable2: string; }>'.`

[image: Property 'variable' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ variable1: string; } | { variable2: string; }>]

I assume it has much to do with my lack of understanding of Typescript and unions, but how would I improve the code below to remove any `ts-lint` errors?

```
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import React from 'react'

type TestScreenParamList = {
  TestScreen: { randomString: string }
  TestScreen2: { randomString2: string }
}

type TestScreenStackProps = StackScreenProps<TestScreenParamList, 'TestScreen' | 'TestScreen2'>

const TestScreen = ({ route, navigation }: TestScreenStackProps) => {
  console.log(route.params.randomString)
  return <></>
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To add some more information, currently what I'm doing to work around this is defining props for every screen, `type TestScreenStackProps = StackScreenProps<TestScreenParamList, 'TestScreen'>`, `type TestScreenStackProps = StackScreenProps<TestScreenParamList, 'TestScreen2'>`. Is this the intended usage? Because I was hoping there'd be a less code voluminous solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to type params for two screens into one.

second argument in StackScreenProps is string and you can not use union in it.
and it's RouteName of your current screen so you cannot use two route name.
params of screen can't change based on from where you are coming

TestScreenParamList is not for only one screen is for whole StackNavigation.
and NativeStackScreenProps will give you types of params based on RouteName you fill in it's second argument.

example:
import type { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { userId: string };
  Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' } | undefined;
};

type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>;
```

if you fill above Profile for Profile Screen then params will be userId an d if you fill Feed for Feed Screen then params will be sort or undefined.

you can also check from here [typescript in react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/)